# Laravel 4 shows no errors at all

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have received a Laravel 4.1 codebase completely hacked, meaning Laravel standards aren't followed or used. The only thing used are routes, not even Eloquent is being used.

The scariest problem for the moment is this, when something breaks, at any level, I always receive a blank screen with the text:

```
@extends('layouts.page')
```

`debug` at `app.php` is set to true, I have `error_reporting(E_ALL)` in `public/index.php`, nothing gets written to the `laravel.log` (it can't be permissions problem as it's a Windows machine with Homestead).

I hope someone had this awful experience before and can help me on this.

Comment: Pretty sure that has happened to me when I had PHP or Blade syntax errors in my code in L4. Can't say I ever found a way around that.

Comment: @mopo922 Unfortunately I'm receiving these errors also from models and controllers.

Comment: did you check the `.env` file for `APP_DEBUG` variable?

Comment: Do you have display_errors=On in your php.ini file?

Comment: @TahaPaksu Laravel 4 doesn't have `.env` files.

Comment: @snixtho Yes, I'm using homestead.

Comment: @user2094178 Oh sorry then.

Answer (score 0):

First check your browser inspect element and see which status code are you receive. Then check your web-server access and error logs. If you dont understand the error where is from, check your composer file.
Finally give some more information about the structure of your customized laravel project.